# turning an intranet website into a public website

Tags: website, intranet

How do I turn an intranet into a public website , my church has a server that has a website that can only be access by the internal Wireless network is it possible to make it public and if so how?

Comment: buy a domain and a hosting to deploy your web site should do the trick

Comment: so i wont be able to use the church's server as the host? there's also a lot of media files.

Comment: you could, but you need a domain

Comment: we do have a domain with a public website but its to static the intranet is more appealing and has the media files ,so how would i go about using the domain we have. is the a tutorial i'm a noob with networking.